# How can I use subsystem default as empty value in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, project-settings

Whenever I create new empty c++ project in Visual studio 2017, the project property  `Linker > System > Subsystem` was `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`
.

I know i can set its property as empty by my hand but I want to change the default as empty value.

Who has an answer about this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide us the specific steps to create new empty c++ project in Visual studio 2017?

I follow the following steps to create, the default as empty value:

1,Click File->New ->Project

[image]

2,Choose Visual C++ -> Empty project. And then add the name of the project.

[image]

3,The project property -> Linker > System > Subsystem was empty value.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the notification delivers to you when i answer my post myself, so i reply here again. Could you please check my result?

Comment: When you create an empty project for c++ in Visual Studio 2017, the subsystem default is empty. I suggest you could follow the steps I provided and try to create a new empty project.